# Having issue while running npm run serve with vue/cli

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I create a project using:

```
vue create test
```

Then going to my repo:

```
cd test
```

but when im trying to lunch by using the command:

```
npm run serve
```

i got an issue :

> INFO  Starting development server...  ERROR  Error: No valid exports
> main found for '/home/paul/PPers/test/node_modules/colorette' Error:
> No valid exports main found for
> '/home/paul/PPers/test/node_modules/colorette'
> at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:9)
> at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:502:14)
> at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
> at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:22)
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960:27)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:855:27)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
> at Object. (/home/paul/PPers/test/node_modules/autoprefixer  /lib/autoprefixer.js:5:17)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm   ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! test@0.1.0 serve:
> `vue-cli-service serve` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> Failed at the test@0.1.0 serve script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
> problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/paul/.npm/_logs/2020-07-07T14_02_14_349Z-debug.log

Here is the log :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok  
1 verbose cli [  
1 verbose cli   '/home/paul/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/bin/node',  
1 verbose cli   '/home/paul/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/bin/npm',  
1 verbose cli   'run',  
1 verbose cli   'serve'  
1 verbose cli ]  
2 info using npm@6.14.5  
3 info using node@v13.6.0  
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]  
5 info lifecycle test@0.1.0~preserve: test@0.1.0  
6 info lifecycle test@0.1.0~serve: test@0.1.0  
7 verbose lifecycle test@0.1.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true  
8 verbose lifecycle test@0.1.0~serve: PATH: /home/paul/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/paul/PPers/test/node_modules/.bin:/home/paul/node_modules/.bin:/home/paul/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/paul/ampl-2019/ampl  
9 verbose lifecycle test@0.1.0~serve: CWD: /home/paul/PPers/test  
10 silly lifecycle test@0.1.0~serve: Args: [ '-c', 'vue-cli-service serve' ]  
11 silly lifecycle test@0.1.0~serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null  
12 info lifecycle test@0.1.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script  
13 verbose stack Error: test@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`  
13 verbose stack Exit status 1  
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/paul/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)  
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:321:20)  
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/paul/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)  
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)  
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)  
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)  
14 verbose pkgid test@0.1.0  
15 verbose cwd /home/paul/PPers/test  
16 verbose Linux 5.3.0-62-generic  
17 verbose argv "/home/paul/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/bin/node" "/home/paul/.nvm/versions/node/v13.6.0/bin/npm" "run" "serve"  
18 verbose node v13.6.0  
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5  
20 error code ELIFECYCLE  
21 error errno 1  
22 error test@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`  
22 error Exit status 1  
23 error Failed at the test@0.1.0 serve script.  
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.  
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: firstly try `npm install` after `cd test`

Comment: Same problem, even after launching npm install ...

Comment: It looks like your error is coming from the collorete npm module `No valid exports main found for
'/home/paul/PPers/test/node_modules/colorette' I looked on npm and that looks like its not even a package. I would go to your node_modules folder and delete that

Comment: Having save issue on reactjs, you get a solution?

Comment: Update your node version. See [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5651) and [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9273).  @NewtonJosé

Comment: @StevenB. i did update my node to v14.5.0 and now its perfectly work thanks for your help :)

Comment: @LeraLam You're very welcome!

Comment: One of the developers on my team is facing this same issue. When trying to run our nuxt.js application running node v13.6.0 and npm 6.13.4. I will try to update node on their machine. Will comment back on the results!

Comment: Can confirm upgrading node to v14.5.0 solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by upgrading node to v14.5.0 based on the comment by @StevenB